# Excel VBA offset property (NOT function)

Tags: excel, offset, vba

I have an Excel file with information in column A and column B. Since these columns could vary in the number of rows I would like to use the function **offset** so that I could print the formula in one time as an array rather than looping over the formula per cell (the dataset contains almost 1 million datapoints).

[image: My data is as follow:]

My code is actually working the way I want it to be I only can't figure out how to print the code in Range(D1:D5). The outcome is now printed in Range(D1:H1). Anybody familiar how to use this offset within a for statement?

```
Sub checkOffset()

Dim example As Range
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Set example = Range("A1:A1")

For i = 1 To LastRow
    example.Offset(0, i + 2).Formula = "=SUM(A" & i & ":B" & i & ")"
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `Offset(Row, Column)` PROPERTY, you want to offset with the increment of row (`i -1`), and 3 columns to the right (from column "A" to column "D")

Try the modified code below:

```
Set example = Range("A1")

For i = 1 To LastRow
    example.Offset(i - 1, 3).Formula = "=SUM(A" & i & ":B" & i & ")"
Next i
```

Answer (score 3):

One way of outputting the formula in one step, without looping, to the entire range, is to use the R1C1 notation:

***Edit: Code modified to properly qualify worksheet references***

```
Option Explicit
Sub checkOffset()

Dim example As Range
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

With sht
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set example = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LastRow, 1))
End With

example.Offset(columnoffset:=3).FormulaR1C1 = "=sum(rc[-3],rc[-2])"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't need to use VBA for this. Simply type =sum(A1:B1) in cell D1 and then [fill it down](http://www.pryor.com/blog/copy-excel-formulas-down-to-fill-a-column/).
2. If you're going to use VBA anyway, use this:

   ```
   Sub checkOffset()
   Dim example As Range
   Dim sht As Worksheet
   Dim LastRow As Long

   Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
   LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

   Set example = Range("A1:A1")

   For i = 1 To LastRow
       example.Offset(i - 1, 3).Formula = "=SUM(A" & i & ":B" & i & ")"
   Next i

   End Sub
   ```

The way `offset` works is with row offset, column offset. You want the column to always be fixed at 3 to the right.

Comment: Yes I understand that, but since it will eventually be used in a larger tool that I am building I want everything to be calculated by vba.